# DST transitions with Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime, dst

I have to calculate the DST transitions in a Java application and querying stackoverflow I found out that joda time has a nice API for doing this quite easily. But actually it gives me the wrong results (or at least it appears to be so).

I have written a sample program to print the transitions of the past 5 and coming 5 years.

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    TimeZone javaZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    DateTimeZone jodaTimezone = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(javaZone);
    Calendar[] dstTransitions;
    DateTime jodaNewYear;
    int dstSavings;
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(javaZone);
    final DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();

    // use the correct timezone for displaying the date and time on console
    df.setTimeZone(javaZone);

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());


    for (int i = -5; i < 5; i++)
    {
        jodaNewYear = new DateTime(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + i, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, jodaTimezone);

        dstTransitions = new Calendar[2];
        dstTransitions[0] = Calendar.getInstance(javaZone);
        dstTransitions[0].setTimeInMillis(jodaTimezone.nextTransition(jodaNewYear.getMillis()));
        dstTransitions[1] = Calendar.getInstance(javaZone);
        dstTransitions[1].setTimeInMillis(jodaTimezone.nextTransition(dstTransitions[0].getTimeInMillis()));

        dstSavings = javaZone.getDSTSavings() / 1000;


        System.out.println("DST transitions for " + javaZone.getID() + " in " + jodaNewYear.getYear() + ":");
        System.out.println("To DST.....: " + df.format(dstTransitions[0].getTime()));
        System.out.println("From DST...: " + df.format(dstTransitions[1].getTime()));
        System.out.println("DST offset.: " + dstSavings + " sec");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

This gives me the following output on my machine (excerpt):

```
DST transitions for Europe/Berlin in 2007:
To DST.....: 25.03.2007 03:00:00
From DST...: 28.10.2007 02:00:00
DST offset.: 3600 sec
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DST transitions for Europe/Berlin in 2008:
To DST.....: 30.03.2008 03:00:00
From DST...: 26.10.2008 02:00:00
DST offset.: 3600 sec
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DST transitions for Europe/Berlin in 2009:
To DST.....: 29.03.2009 03:00:00
From DST...: 25.10.2009 02:00:00
DST offset.: 3600 sec
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DST transitions for Europe/Berlin in 2010:
To DST.....: 28.03.2010 03:00:00
From DST...: 31.10.2010 02:00:00
DST offset.: 3600 sec
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DST transitions for Europe/Berlin in 2011:
To DST.....: 27.03.2011 03:00:00
From DST...: 30.10.2011 02:00:00
DST offset.: 3600 sec
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DST transitions for Europe/Berlin in 2012:
To DST.....: 25.03.2012 03:00:00
From DST...: 28.10.2012 02:00:00
DST offset.: 3600 sec
```

Looks quite ok but I have a problem with the times. Actually the transition to DST takes place on the last sunday in march at 2:00 am while the backward transition takes place on the last sunday of october at 3:00 am. So the times of the joda transitions seem to be wrong.

I am completely new to the joda API so I may have overlooked something. May actual question is: how can I determine the correct transition times?

Regards

Sebastian

Answer (score 3):

There is a discontinuity at the transition. `25.03.12 02:00` is the same instant as `25.03.12 03:00`, and vice-versa in October, except things are more complex since the hour 02:00 to 03:00 repeats.

Looks like Joda is giving you the time on the "later" side of the transition -- I.e. what the time is after the transition occurs.  To find the time just "before" the transition, adjust by the DST offset.

Comment: This works only for the October transition. For the March transition it results in 1:00 am.

Comment: OK. I actually solved it for the case I have. In the timezone Europe/Berlin the instant 2:00:00 am on the last sunday of March just does not exist according to Java's Calendar class. When calculating the transition with joda time I get 3:00:00 am as stated above. But when I subtract just one millisecond I will get 1:59:59.999.

Comment: That is correct.  My answer was a little unclear on that transition.